# Why do I get the "name does not exist in current context" error even though I'm using name in the same scope as its declaration

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and trying to understand how things work. Why do I get the "name does not exist in current context" error even though I'm using name in the same scope as its declaration? Here is my code:

```
public class GradeBook
    {
        protected List<float> grades;

        public event NameChangedDelegate NameChanged;

        private string _name;

       _name = "blah"; //<---error happens here

       //more code
    }
```

Comment: private string _name = "blah"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executable code (alternatively put, instructions, expressions, or more rigorously; statements) cannot exist "in a vacuum" in C#.

For example, in the class scope you can only have variable declarations and methods. `_variable = "blah"` is **not allowed**.

That code must reside in some method. Alternatively, if you just want to *initialize* the member you can do so inline:

`private string _name = "blah"`

Answer (score 3):

You've got code *not* inside a class method inside of your class definition.

```
public class GradeBook
    {
        protected List<float> grades;

        public event NameChangedDelegate NameChanged;

        private string _name;

       void someMethod() {
          _name = "blah";
       }

       //more code
    }
```

- or - as @dan says